# The authentication is working properly but whenever I typed the wrong email address, my server is getting crashed

Tags: node.js, reactjs, node-oracledb

The server is keep getting crashed whenever i typed the wrong email address, i understood the problem, but can anyone tell me how to solve this.
Problem:Here the authentication is done for password only, if the password is wrong it is giving me the right error which is "Incorrect email or address", but not give this one when i try with wrong email address.
so i need the authentication for the email address also from my understanding this much i summarized.

Logins.js(API)

```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
 var oracledb = require('oracledb');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var config = require(__dirname + '../../config.js');
import { Redirect } from 'react-router'
// var redirect = require("express-redirect");
// var express = require("express");
//var passport = require('passport');
//var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
//var history = require('history');
//import post from './users';
//var cors = require('cors');
// var history = require('browser-history');
// var app = express();
// redirect(app);
// const targetBaseUrl = '/Signup';

function post(req, res, next) {
    console.log('oye')
    oracledb.getConnection(
        config.database,
        function(err, connection){
            if (err) {
                console.log('haha')
                return next(err);
                // console.log(err);
            }
            console.log('fuha')

            connection.execute(
                'select id as "id", ' +
                '   email as "email", ' +
                '   password as "password", ' +
                '   role as "role" ' +
                'from jsao_users ' +
                'where email = :email',
                {
                    email: req.body.email.toLowerCase()
                },
                {
                    outFormat: oracledb.OBJECT
                },
                function(err, results){
                    var user;
                    console.log('huo')
                    console.log(err)
                    //console.log(results)
                        console.log(results.rows[0])
``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
                    if (results.rows[0] === undefined) {
                        console.log('hiiiiiii')
                        return <Redirect to='/Signup'  />
                        // app.redirect(targetBaseUrl);
                        // history.push("/Main");
                    }
``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
                    //     else {connection.release(function(err) {
                    //         console.log('hy')
                    //         if (err) {
                    //             console.log('joker')
                    //             console.error(err.message);
                    //         }
                    //     });

                    //     return next(err);
                    //     // console.log(err);
                    // }

                    user = results.rows[0];
                    //debugger;

                    console.log(user)
                    bcrypt.compare(req.body.password,user.password, function(err, pwMatch) {
                        var payload;

                        if (err) {
                            console.log('wrong');
                            return next(err);
                        }

                        /*if (result == true) {
                            //res.redirect('http://localhost:3000/Main');
                            //res.end();
                        } 

                        else {
                         res.send('Incorrect password');
                         //res.redirect('/Signin');
                         //res.end();
                        }

                        /*if(req.body.password != user.password){
                            res.json({success: false, message: 'passwords do not match'});
                        }*/
                        /*if(req.body.password == user.password) {
                            this.props.history.push("/Main");
                        }*/
                        if(pwMatch) {
                             //this.props.history.push("/Main");
                             console.log("password matched");
                        }
                        else {
                            res.status(401).send({message: 'Invalid email or password.'});
                            return;
                        }

                        payload = {
                            sub: user.email,
                            role: user.role
                        };

                        res.status(200).json({
                            user: user,
                            token: jwt.sign(payload, config.jwtSecretKey, {expiresIn: "60m" }),

                        });
                    });
                    //res.status(404).end();
                    connection.release(function(err) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.error(err.message);
                        }
                    }); 

                });
        }
    );
}

module.exports.post = post;



Signin.js (Front-end)

import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Button, FormGroup, FormControl, ControlLabel } from "react-bootstrap";
import axios from 'axios';
import "./Signin.css";

class Signin extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      email: "",
      password: ""
    };
  }

  validateForm() {
    return this.state.email.length > 0 && this.state.password.length > 0;
  }

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.id]: event.target.value
    });
  }
```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const user = {
        email: this.state.email,
        password : this.state.password
      };
  // API CALL
      axios.post(`http://localhost:4000/api/logins`, user)
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res);
          console.log(res.data);
          //console.log("successful");
        })
        //this.props.history.push("/Main");
  }
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Login">
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <FormGroup controlId="email" bsSize="large">
            <ControlLabel>Email</ControlLabel>
            <FormControl
              autoFocus
              type="email"
              value={this.state.email}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup controlId="password" bsSize="large">
            <ControlLabel>Password</ControlLabel>
            <FormControl
              value={this.state.password}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              type="password"
            />
          </FormGroup>
          <Button
            block
            bsSize="large"
            disabled={!this.validateForm()}
            type="submit"
          >
            Login
          </Button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Signin;


The expected result for the wrong email address is "Invalid email or password"
But instead getting this error:
C:\Users\anura\Desktop\reactApp\eclaims\src\Backend\routes\logins.js:49
                    bcrypt.compare(req.body.password,user.password, function(err, pwMatch) {
                                                          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'password' of undefined
    at C:\Users\anura\Desktop\reactApp\eclaims\src\Backend\routes\logins.js:49:59
    at fetchRowsCb (C:\Users\anura\Desktop\reactApp\eclaims\src\Backend\node_modules\oracledb\lib\connection.js:109:7)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Comment: Please post minimal code for better understanding.

Comment: ok, I will not put the long codes from now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app crashed because you didn't throw exception and return immediately when getting user not found err, because the email is invalid, user variable is null, you cannot read property password of null or undefined

```
if (err) {
   connection.release(function(err) {
      if (err) {
         console.error(err.message);
      }
   });
   // MUST RETURN HERE !!!
   //return next(err);
   console.log(err);
}

user = results.rows[0];
// user IS NULL HERE, CANNOT READ PROPERTY OF NULL OR UNDERFINED

//debugger;
bcrypt.compare(req.body.password,user.password, function(err, pwMatch) {
```

Comment: I have already uncomment the return next(err); but still i am getting the same error,and how the user = results.rows[0]; is null ? It is reading the values isn't it ?

Comment: @Anurag when you entered invalid email, how can you get user in db by that email?

Comment: Now i got it what are saying, but then can you tell me where to put code to check if the email address is not found in db , it should throw please register or user not found.

Comment: In `if (err){}`, you should return "Email or password is invalid" and stop login process, no matter what is that error, wrong email, wrong password, user not found... This is to avoid hacker can guess what your system has. Let say, he entered a random email, and you throw message "Password is not correct" then he know that is the existing email and focus to the password...

Comment: The error is Cannot read property 'password' of undefined, means user is undefined. User is undefined because the invalid email was not in database, means user with that email was not found. If you input an invalid email, you will not get any user, why do you need to check it's password?

Comment: I have edited the code and want to redirect to new page, can you suggest me how to redirect to new page, because i already tried bunch of stuff and its not working.

Comment: You cannot redirect to new page in your API (server side). The API should only check and response status code and message (optional). Then in client side (Signin.js), you base on the status code to redirect, e.g if status code is 200, redirect to home page, if status code is 401, alert message "Invalid email or password."

Comment: Thanks to your help, now I am half way there. I am really glad that you helped. Keep helping the peoples

Answer (score 1):

In your `callback` check for empty values when no entry in db found.

```
function(err, results){
  var user;
  ...

  // put check for empty value if no entries found
  if (results.length === 0) {
    res.status(401).send({message: 'Invalid email or password.'});
  } else {
    // rest of your code
    user = results.rows[0];
    //debugger;
    bcrypt.compare(req.body.password,user.password, function(err, pwMatch) {
      var payload;
    }
    ...
  }
}
```